# What's the right way to compute integral base-2 logarithms at compile-time?

Tags: c++11, constants, constexpr, logarithm, idioms

I have some positive constant value that comes from a different library than mine, call it `the_val`. Now, I want `log_of_the_val` to be floor(log_2(the_val))  - not speaking in C++ code - and I want that to happen at compile time, of course.

Now, with gcc, I could do something like

```
decltype(the_val) log_of_the_val = sizeof(the_val) * CHAR_BIT - __builtin_clz(the_val) - 1;
```

and that should work, I think (length - number of heading zeros). Otherwise, I could implement a constexpr function myself for it, but I'm betting that there's something else, and simpler, and portable, that I could use at compile-time. ... question is, what would that be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to use `std::log2` from `<cmath>`, but that isn't specified to be constexpr - it is under gcc, but not under clang. (Actually, libstdc++ `std::log2` calls `__builtin_log2`, which is constexpr under gcc.)

`__builtin_clz` is constexpr under both gcc and clang, so you may want to use that.

The fully portable solution is to write a recursive constexpr integral log2:

```
constexpr unsigned cilog2(unsigned val) { return val ? 1 + cilog2(val >> 1) : -1; }
```

Comment: What's the rationale for -1 ? Also, fixed the off-by-1 I think.

Comment: @einpoklum `log2(0)` is an error, but it simplifies the implementation to return `-1`. An alternative would be to terminate the recursion on `1`, and throw `std::domain_error` for `0`: `constexpr unsigned cilog2(unsigned val) { return val > 1 ? 1 + cilog2(val >> 1) : val == 1 ? 0 : throw std::domain_error{"cilog2(0)"}; }`